# Failed to CREATE PROCEDURE - 1307

Tags: mysql

HI, I did a backup of mysql server to update the developer's database with real company data but when restoring only procedures were not created, but existing ones where deleted it seems that DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS is executing but then it fails on creating the procedure, the backup restores successfully on the main server so the file is ok, how can I solve this?
 thanks in advance.

Comment: Which versions of Mysql are you running on each server?

Comment: 5.1.............